# Mongoose schema validate without creating a document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Say I have a javascript object (the `data`) and I want to check to see if it conforms to a given `Schema` that I've defined.

Is there a way to do this without turning the schema into a model, creating an instance of that model populated with the `data`, and running `mymodel.validate()`?

I'd love to have a `Schema(definition).validate(data, callback)`, but the `validate` function is defined on the `Document` class, from what I could tell.

Comment: `model.create(data).validate()` doesn't seem that hard to me, and is probably your best option. Why do you want another syntax?

Comment: No, it's not possible without digging through the internals.

Comment: :( I don't want to creaete a model for this schema. but maybe I'll have to. Seems like it ought to be extractable.

Comment: +1 My use case is that I want to validate documents on the client. My *other* use case is that I want to use Mongoose's schema format to validate internal messages which I never intend to store in the DB.

Comment: What's the problem with creating a new doc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## 2021 update

Mongoose added that functionality as [Model.validate(...)](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.validate) back in 2019 (v5.8.0):

You can:

```js
try {
  await Model.validate({ name: 'Hafez', age: 26 });
} catch (err) {
  err instanceof mongoose.Error.ValidationError; // true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to perform that with the help of custom validators. When the validation declined, it failed to save the document into the database.

Or another way to do that through validate() function provided by MongoDB with the same schema as you defined.

Answer (score 0):

You can validate your schema on the Mongo side [link](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/schema-validation/)
For example:

```
db.createCollection("students", {
   validator: {
      $jsonSchema: {
         bsonType: "object",
         required: [ "name" ],
         properties: {
            name: {
               bsonType: "string",
               description: "must be a string and is required"
            },
            year: {
               bsonType: "int",
               minimum: 2017,
               maximum: 3017,
               description: "must be an integer in [ 2017, 3017 ] and is required"
            }
         }
      }
   }
})
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29861893)